# Sanitizing Sinatra user inputs

Tags: ruby, backbone.js, sinatra, sanitization

I am building a Sinatra and backbone app and I'm using the [sanitize](https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize/) gem to clean the user inputs.

I want to know what is the best practice, to sanitize at the app.rb level, at the routes.rb or at the model.rb level?

Does it even make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

Rule of thumb - as early as it's possible and/or makes sense. Reason is simple and practical: sooner it's sanitized - less probability for successful intrusion.

Comment: The idea is to sanitize an input before it is submited to the server.

So the question remains, then; What is being called as soon as you click a submit button, app.rb, routes.rb or model.rb?

Comment: it's your app - I can only guess. sinatra does not force you to use particular project structure.

Comment: Like JimiSpire says, sanitise before submission with backbone, but since one of the reasons to sanitise is because of possible intrusion, *always* sanitise on the server side too. Always, always, always. An attacker would bypass any sanitising code on the client side if they wanted to do damage that way. +1 to both of you.